# ESB WSO2 Adding a property into a XML file using Enrich, Iterate and Filter mediator

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I want to sent a Postman request with a xml file like this to my api:

```
<data>
    <user>
        <name>Andrei</name>
        <adress>Tudor Vladimirescu, nr2</adress>
        <cnp>123456789</cnp>
        <age>22</age>
    </user>
    <user>
        <name>Ana</name>
        <adress>Str. Pacurari, nr1</adress>
        <cnp>123456789</cnp>
        <age>26</age>
    </user>
    <user>
        <name>Andreea</name>
        <adress>Tudor Vladimirescu, nr1</adress>
        <cnp>123456789</cnp>
        <age>20</age>
    </user>
</data>
```

And I want to add a `<valid>Yes/No</valid>` tag to each `<user>` based on the age. For example: if the age is above 23, the value of the `valid` tag should be `Yes`. I want to send the modified message to another API.
I know that I should use Enrich, Iterate and Filter mediators but I really need some help because I'm a beginner. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @EAGame,

Can you please look into below blog?  https://medium.com/think-integration/modify-payload-by-adding-a-child-element-using-enrich-mediator-3af63958278

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `Iterate` mediator as you need backend call and `filter` mediator used to set age is valid or not for each element and finally used `enrich` mediator to achieve your usecase.

```
<!-- iteration of incoming user data -->
            <iterate expression="//data/user" id="iterateuser" sequential="true">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <property expression="//age/text()" name="age" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                         <log level="custom">
                <property name="Inside Iterator" value="is called*****"/>
                <property expression="get-property('age')" name="age"/>
            </log>
             <!-- fiter to find valid age  or not-->
                        <filter xpath="get-property('age')>='23'">
                            <then>
                                <property name="valid" scope="default" type="STRING" value="Yes"/>
                            </then>
                            <else>
                                <property name="valid" scope="default" type="STRING" value="No"/>
                            </else>
                        </filter>
                         <!-- enrich to add valid tag to existing payload-->
                        <enrich>
                            <source clone="true" type="inline">
                                <valid xmlns=""/>
                            </source>
                            <target action="child" xmlns:ns="http://www.wso2.org/types" xpath="//user"/>
                        </enrich>
                        <!-- enrich to add valid property value with validtag-->
                        <enrich>
                            <source clone="true" property="valid" type="property"/>
                            <target xpath="//valid"/>
                        </enrich>
                        <log level="full"/>
                        <!-- make an external endpoint call here -->
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </iterate>
```

Input:

```
<data>
    <user>
        <name>Andrei</name>
        <adress>Tudor Vladimirescu, nr2</adress>
        <cnp>123456789</cnp>
        <age>22</age>
    </user>
    <user>
        <name>Ana</name>
        <adress>Str. Pacurari, nr1</adress>
        <cnp>123456789</cnp>
        <age>26</age>
    </user>
    <user>
        <name>Andreea</name>
        <adress>Tudor Vladimirescu, nr1</adress>
        <cnp>123456789</cnp>
        <age>20</age>
    </user>
</data>
```

Log for iteration:

```
[2022-03-15 12:27:23,032]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - Inside Iterator = is called*****, age = 22
[2022-03-15 12:27:23,032]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: /enrichapi, MessageID: urn:uuid:8101fdcc-0a29-4bea-a8f1-b8ad80f0c6ff, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><user>
        <name>Andrei</name>
        <adress>Tudor Vladimirescu, nr2</adress>
        <cnp>123456789</cnp>
        <age>22</age>
    <valid>No</valid></user></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2022-03-15 12:27:23,032]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - Inside Iterator = is called*****, age = 26
[2022-03-15 12:27:23,040]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: /enrichapi, MessageID: urn:uuid:b01f8b29-9fe5-43e6-a0ed-0a61d395fd1a, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><user>
        <name>Ana</name>
        <adress>Str. Pacurari, nr1</adress>
        <cnp>123456789</cnp>
        <age>26</age>
    <valid>Yes</valid></user></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2022-03-15 12:27:23,053]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - Inside Iterator = is called*****, age = 20
[2022-03-15 12:27:23,053]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: /enrichapi, MessageID: urn:uuid:1feeb723-8a72-475a-b014-cda2e7b7a90a, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><user>
        <name>Andreea</name>
        <adress>Tudor Vladimirescu, nr1</adress>
        <cnp>123456789</cnp>
        <age>20</age>
    <valid>No</valid></user></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

If you noticed above log `<valid>No</valid>` or `<valid>Yes</valid>` is added to payload.

Post this, you can make external endpoint call inside iterator.

Ref:
[Enrich Mediator](http://wso2experts.com/ei/enrich-mediator/)